# Combine space separated incomplete words to form meaningful words

Tags: python, nlp, text-processing

I'm new to NLP and couldn't find the right solution anywhere. I want to combine the space-separated incomplete words in a sentence to make complete words.

For e.g., the follwoing sentence of incomplete words

```
Sl  ight s t randing at the   root  of the   mes en tery
```

should change to

```
Slight stranding at the root of the mesentery
```

Please help me as I have no idea where to start from.

Answer (score 0):

If your main goal is to extract specific information from this text, you can create a dataset and [train](https://spacy.io/usage/training) a spaCy NER model to do the same.

- Stimulate the spaces (introduce spaces randomly)

```
text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"

def introduce_spaces(text):
    for i in enumerate(text, p=0.1):
        if random.random() > p:
            text.insert(i, " ")
    return text

>>> {"text": "The qu ick b row n fo x jumps over the lazy dog", "entities":[("COLOR", 10, 7), ("ANIMAL", 12, 15), ...]}
```

Note that this is a very crude implementation. You can implement something like this if you know about the distribution of space in your text. You will have to implement the distribution of your case.

- Annotate a corpus: Most likely, you won't know the distribution. In this case, you need to create a dataset on your own. You can use [prodigy](https://prodi.gy) to do that.

Once you have trained your model, you will be able to identify and extract the info, even though its space separated.